# Comparing Performance and Determining Scaling

Tags: regression, group-differences

My understanding of statistics is fairly basic, but I'll try to be precise here.

`Method X` of doing something exists and can be timed with a particular method of unknown accuracy. I have created `Method Y`, but it is timed with a different method, also of unknown accuracy (to be specific, I am timing a process). I can run as many trials as I like with the same data or with different data (within reason). I assume the two timing methods are reasonably precise, but I have no measurement of error.

I want to do two things:

1. Compare `Method Y` with `Method X` to see how much of a timing difference I am getting and if it is significant. Basically, I want to answer the question: How much better does `Method Y` perform, considering it is more expensive and tedious to set up.
2. Run `Method Y` several times with different input sizes to see how it scales. I want to answer: what sort of overhead is involved, and can I derive some sort of function to predict how it will behave with a dataset of a particular size.

I assume the first will involve some sort of T-test and the latter will be a regression, but I would like some advice on what sort of tests I should look at and possibly how many trials I should use.

A more detailed explanation follows here in case it helps:
I have a program that can run in threaded mode on a single machine, I can time the performance with the built in Unix/Linux `time` function. This is `Method X`.

I have created a distributed version of this program (`Method Y`), and I want to get a handle on the overhead and the scaling. I also want to see if it is worth using (if the performance isn't that much better, it is a waste). My timing function is here built into the distributed system and is far less granular.

My input data comes in two parts: a query file (the variable being size) and a database to check it against (variable is size, but it comes in several pieces, each of a different size).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is a "Way" the same as a "Method"?

Comment: Eeep, forgot to fix that when I went back to edit.